# How to detect memory leak in system_server

Tags: android, server, system

Produce steps:

1. launch demo activity(almost empty) and press KEY_BACK
2. check the memory info of system_server with AndroidStudio Profiler(View->Tool Windows->Profiler)
3. repeat step1 and check the memory info of system_server

Result:

> the native memory keeps increasing, and after a long time (20h+), the
>   low memory killer will start kill system apps which makes the device
>   abnormal.

We suppose that the native code has some memory leak, but the process is system_server, we can not locate the code or library...
Is there any way we can find out the code or library which caused the leak?

Comment: check and leak Canary library for find important memory leak

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59262784/memory-usages-high-slow-application-response-used-memory-value-not-decreasin/59383874#59383874